# Android FBReaderj - The import org.geometerplus.fbreader.filetype cannot be resolved

Tags: android

I have just got the latest (1.5.5) FBReaderj from Github (https://github.com/geometer/FBReaderJ)

After running ant release (successfully) I created a new android project from existing sources into eclipse and I now face 3 errors in different files all stating "The import org.geometerplus.fbreader.filetype cannot be resolved"

The offending line of code is this

```
import org.geometerplus.fbreader.filetype.*;
```

I have looked in the relevant folder and sure enough there are no files named filetype. anything

So where do I get these files from and what should be in them?

Comment: I have encountered the same problem